# Simulating a click in the game window

Tags: python, c++, winapi, pywin32

The problem is that I already have a working program that sends a click to an inactive window that is not on TOPLEVEL, but it does not work with all windows.
And I cannot understand what is the reason for this behavior.
When I filter messages with spy ++, they are exactly the same as with a real mouse click, but in the end the game does not respond.

Initially, I coded it in python, but in the end it didn't work out for me and I decided to try C ++, despite the fact that I have no experience.
Here's what I managed to put together in C ++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <conio.h>

LPCTSTR WindowName = L"Raid: Shadow Legends";
HWND hMU = FindWindow(NULL, WindowName);
int main() {
    if (hMU)
    {
        int x = 16; //selected values ​​based on the readings of spy ++
        int y = 266; //
        WINDOWPOS wp = { hMU, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE };
        
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hMU, MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE));
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, (WPARAM)hMU, MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT, WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, 0, (LPARAM)& wp);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, 0, (LPARAM)& wp);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, 1, 0);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_NCACTIVATE, 1, 0);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_CLICKACTIVE, 0);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hMU, MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT, WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
        PostMessage(hMU, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
        PostMessage(hMU, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
        SendMessage(hMU, WM_CAPTURECHANGED, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The code is probably redundant or even bad, but I don't pay attention to it. I followed the path of exact copying of messages on mouse click. Sorry for this.
I will accept any help. Also a Python solution would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps the game employs anti-cheat measures.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik 
It is possible. Interestingly, this same game completely accepts my code with simulated keystrokes, but it does not work with simulated mouse clicks.

Comment: There is more to simulating input than just sending window messages (and FYI, some of those messages need to be *posted* with `PostMessage()`, not *sent* with `SendMessage()`). The correct way to simulate input is with `SendInput()`, but that won't work if the coordinates of the simulated input are covered up by another window. Does the game's window react to UIAutomation instead?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to send the corresponding message to the game window.

You can refer to:[How to simulate mouse click in a Directx game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094278/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-a-directx-game).

You can position the focus to the corresponding window by using [`AttachThreadInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput), [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) [`SetActiveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setactivewindow) and [`SetFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus).

Then send the specified message through [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043). [I warned you: The dangers of attaching input queues](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080801-00/?p=21393). [Sharing an input queue takes what used to be asynchronous and makes it synchronous, like focus changes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143).

Comment: yes, but I need the window to remain in the same position, that is, so that it does not appear in front

Comment: @D3-one6 I think the games uses DirectInput so you can't use SendMessage to send mouse events or keyboard events to it.So you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735029/directx-game-hook